# Change color of DataGrid row in UserControl

Tags: wpf, datagrid, user-controls

I'm working in a project using UserControl i need to change row color while I surfed the web for an answer i always seen them using a loop and use DataGrid.Rows and it's not available in System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid so how can i change to System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid or change the background color of the rows
when i add a datagrid (drag and drop) it's always takes System.Windows.Controls and when i uses DataGrid.row or DataGrid.Rows I get this error

> 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you looking to just change the color of them all? Alternating rows? Conditional based on data in the row?

Comment: condition based from data in the row or from Mysql because i'm filling it from MySql database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change WPF Datagrid Row Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056657/change-wpf-datagrid-row-color)

Comment: they are using e.Row (DataGrid.row and it's not available in System.Window.Controls) i mentioned above

Comment: @klaus that's not true. They're using DataGridRowEventArgs.Row, not DataGrid.Row. I just verified by adding a DataGrid in xaml, and creating an event handler for the LoadingRow event. Personally I would go with the accepted answer and go with RowStyle and DataTriggers

Comment: You're going to get into virtualization horrors next if you insist on doing this in code behind. You'll thank yourself if you listen to @Rowbear and [do it with RowStyle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10056693/424129).

Comment: Check my article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683429/Guide-to-WPF-DataGrid-formatting-using-bindings to get a detailed explanation of datagrid formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a style of **RowStyle**

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource converter}}" Value="true"> <!-- You can create a converter to define your condition -->
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```